# Modify dynamic input string

Tags: java, regex

I'm working on one requirement. I receives input string in below format.

```
A:82% X 18% Y B:100% X C:82% X 18% Y AB:60% X 20% Y 20% ZZ
```

String Explanation,

```
1) String consists of multiple material names like below are the material names present in above mentioned string

        A
        B
        C
        AB

2) Every material is made up of different constituents, For example A is made from 82% of X and 18% of Y. In another input string according to material name the ratio of ingredients can split accordingly. But total is always 100%

3) A string can have multiple material names and one material can be made of n number of ingredients (Total percentage would be 100%)
```

I want to convert my input string in below format

```
#A:82% X,18% Y #B:100% X #C:82% X, 18% Y #AB:60% X,20% Y,20% ZZ
```

I'm able to achieve hash part using regex, code snippet

```
String inp = "A:82% X 18% Y B:100% X C:82% X 18% Y AB:82% X 18% Y";
String regex = "(\\b[A-Za-z]{1,}\\:\\b)";   
System.out.println(inp.replaceAll(regex, "#$1"));
```

But am not able to handle or not getting idea for setting up commas in between ingredients of specific material.

Any suggestions please....?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution leveraging Java 8 streams and regex.

```
String input = "A:82% X 18% Y B:100% X C:82% X 18% Y AB:60% X 20% Y 20% ZZ";
System.out.println(
        // streaming chunks of input delimited by start of expression
        Stream.of(
            input.split("(?=(^| )\\p{L}+:)")
        )
        // mapping each chunk to replacements
        .map(
            s ->
                // pre-pending # 
                s.replaceAll("(\\p{L}+:)", "#$1")
                // pre-pending comma for multiple value percentages
                .replaceAll("(?= \\d+% \\p{L})",",")
        )
        // collecting by trivial join
        .collect(Collectors.joining())
);
```

**Output**

```
#A:82% X, 18% Y #B:100% X #C:82% X, 18% Y #AB:60% X, 20% Y, 20% ZZ
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead:

```
String inp = "A:82% X 18% Y B:100% X C:82% X 18% Y AB:82% X 18% Y";
String regex = "(\\b[A-Za-z]{1,}\\:\\b)";
String regexToPlaceComa = "(\\d{1,3}% [a-zA-Z]+) (?!#)";
inp = inp.replaceAll(regex, "#$1");
inp = inp.replaceAll(regexToPlaceComa, "$1,");
System.out.println(inp);
```

Also in your regex: "\\" character escape before ":" is redundant, and "{1,}" you can replace with "+" like below:

```
regex = "(\\b[A-Za-z]+:\\b)";
```